# How to clear/drop/empty a MongoDb collection with Casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I started using MongoDb in Scala via Casbah but cannot find on the Casbah documentation / google the way to drop the content of a collection.
The [MongoDd](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Removing) doc says the MongoDb shell command to do so is

```
db.things.remove({});
```

But how can we achieve the same via Casbah?

Thanks in advance,

Olivier

Comment: Excuse my nitpicking, but it's called a collection in MongoDB, not a table. I took the freedom to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Casbah's equivalent to the shells `{}` empty document operator is `MongoDBObject.empty

This should work -

```
db.things.remove(MongoDBObject.empty)
```

Comment: Hi @Brendan W. McAdams, do you have any Idea how can I instantiate mongo cli in scala?